# when i checked radiobuttonlist inside listview it always return this error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

i use two listview(ListView1(outer),ColorListView(inner)) and radiobuttonlist inside the second listview.
i binded radiobuttonlist in page load.
when i check if radiobuttonlist is checked in (listview1_itemcommand) ,give me this message (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

```html
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductDetailsDS" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" OnDataBound="ListView1_DataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- /header -->
                    <asp:Label ID="ResultLabel" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="product-details-wrapper">
                        <h2 class="product-name">
                            <%# Eval("ProductTitle") %>
                        </h2>
                        <!-- /.product-name -->

                        <div class="product-status">
                            <span>by :</span>
                            <span>-</span>
                            <small><%# Eval("DesignerName") %></small>
                        </div>




                        <div class="product-actions-wrapper">
                            <form action="product-quick-view.html" method="POST">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="p_color">Color</label>

                                            <div class="wiget-content">
                                                <div class="colors square">
                                                    <asp:ListView ID="ColorListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductColorsDS" OnItemCommand="ColorListView_ItemCommand">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                           
                                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                                      

                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <LayoutTemplate>
                                                            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                                                        </LayoutTemplate>
                                                    </asp:ListView>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ProductColorsDS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" SelectMethod="Read" TypeName="BOL.ProductsColorsImages">
                                                <SelectParameters>
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2" Name="ActionCode" Type="String" />
                                                    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter Name="ColorID" Type="Int32" />
                                                </SelectParameters>
                                            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                           

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="p_size">
                                                Size <a href="../../sizechart.html" class="awe-button product-quick-view" data-toggle="tooltip" title="size chart">
                                                    <i class="icon icon-eye"></i></a>
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="SizesDropDownList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="ProductSizesDS" DataTextField="SizeTitle" DataValueField="SizeID">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                  
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="p_qty">Qty</label>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="QuantityDropDownList" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                                                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                         
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                    
                            </form>
                            <!-- /.form -->

                            <div class="product-list-actions">
                                <span class="product-price">
                                    <%# ( Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NewPrice")) == 0) ? "<span class=\"offer\">"+ Eval("Price", "{0:C}").ToString()+"</span>":"<span class='actual'>"+ Eval("Price","{0:C}").ToString()+"</span> <del class=\"offer\">"+Eval("NewPrice", "{0:C}").ToString()+"</del>" %>
                                </span>
                                <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                <!-- /.product-price -->
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="BuyLinkButton" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' CommandName="Buy" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                                                 Add to cart</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="WishListLinkButton" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' CommandName="WishList" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-outline btn-block">
                                                 Add to Wishlist</asp:LinkButton>
                         
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="product-description">
                            <h3>Descriptions</h3>
                            <p>
                                <%# Eval("Description") %>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ProductDetailsDS" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="Read" TypeName="BOL.Products">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2" Name="ActionCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryGroupID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SearchText" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

```html
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }

        protected void BindData()
        {
                ListView1.DataBind();
                BOL.ProductsColorsImages dd = new BOL.ProductsColorsImages();
                DAL.Products.ProductsColorImagesDataTable dt = new DAL.Products.ProductsColorImagesDataTable();
                dt = dd.Read("2", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProductID"]), 0);


                foreach (ListViewItem inner in ListView1.Items)
                {

                    ListView innerlistview = (ListView)inner.FindControl("ColorListView");

                    foreach (ListViewItem item in innerlistview.Items)
                    {
                        RadioButtonList rad = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            ListItem newitem = new ListItem();
                            newitem.Text = "";
                            newitem.Value = row[3].ToString();
                            //string a="<a href='../Uploades/ProductsColors/"+row[2].ToString()+"' class= '"+"colorss" +"'"+" style='cursor:default'"+" rel='"+"enlargeimage"+"' rev='"+"targetdiv:loadarea2,trigger:click,preload:none,fx:fade'"+">"+"<span style=background-color:" + row[4] + "><span style=background-color:" + row[4] + "></span></span></a>";
                            string a = "<span style=background-color:" + row[4] + "><span style=background-color:" + row[4] + "></span></span>";

                            //rad.Items.Add(a + newitem);
                            rad.Items.Add(new ListItem(a, row[3].ToString()));
                            rad.DataBind();
                        }
                        break;
                    }


                }
            
        }

        protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            
            Label ResultLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ResultLabel");
            ResultLabel.Visible = false;

            string colortext = "";
            ListView innerlistview = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("ColorListView");

            foreach (ListViewItem item in innerlistview.Items)
            {
                RadioButtonList rad = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
                if (rad.SelectedIndex > -1)
                {
                    ResultLabel.Text = "You must select Color . ";
                    ResultLabel.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    colortext = rad.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() ;
                }

            }
}

 protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataBind();
        }
```